# Creating a multilayer pie chart with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart

How can I create a multi layer pie chart with d3.js which looks like below

[image]

Every section doesn't have an inner subsection and when it has a subsection then it has darker color than the outer subsection as shown in the above image.

I tried searching for multilayer pie chart but what all I could do is this.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZpQ3x/

Here is corresponding javascript code

```
var dataset = {
  final: [7000],
  process: [1000, 1000, 1000, 7000],
  initial: [10000],
};

var width = 660,
    height = 500,
    cwidth = 75;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("class","wrapper")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")

var gs = svg.selectAll("g.wrapper").data(d3.values(dataset)).enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("id",function(d,i){
            return Object.keys(dataset)[i];
        });

var gsLabels = svg.selectAll("g.wrapper").data(d3.values(dataset)).enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("id",function(d,i){
            return "label_" + Object.keys(dataset)[i];
        });

var count = 0;
var path = gs.selectAll("path")
    .data(function(d) { return pie(d); })
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", function(d, i, j) { 
        d._tmp = d.endAngle;
        d.endAngle = d.startAngle;
        if(Object.keys(dataset)[j] === "final"){
            d.arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(cwidth*j).outerRadius(cwidth*(j+1)); 
        }
        else{
            d.arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(10+cwidth*j).outerRadius(cwidth*(j+1)); 
        }
        return d.arc(d);
        })
    .transition().delay(function(d, i, j) {
            return i * 500; 
    }).duration(500)
    .attrTween('d', function(d,x,y) {
       var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle, d._tmp);
       return function(t) {
           d.endAngle = i(t);
         return d.arc(d);
       }
    });
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Isnt this close to what you want https://pankajkumar005.wordpress.com/2015/08/14/multilevel-pie-chart-using-d3/

Comment: @Cyril I came across mentioned code while searching but if you look closely one section is not coming all the way from circumference to center of the pie, which is desired by me.

Comment: One thing is not clear inner subsection sometimes is long and sometimes its short whats the criteria for that. Why aren't all subsection having same radius?

Comment: Suppose, there are 5 main sections in the pie; implies 20% for each for them. Now in each subsection there are two levels; dark color is shown for percentage of level 1 and the light color is for percentage of level  2. So for each main section the inner subsection vary.I hope that is clear now

Comment: perhaps you could have the pie chart you have there correspond to your data ? How exactly do you want it to look? Could you explain your dataset :)

Comment: The dataset you can see like this:
Main variable `X = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]`
`X1=[20, 0, 13, 100, 50] `(corresponding to dark color - say level 1)

`X2 = X-X1`

X and X1 will be fed to the code.

Is it fine now?

Comment: is the pie chart split up equally depending how many x values you have ? So if you have 5, the pie chart is just split into 5 ?

Comment: No.  That was a specific example; it could be be `X= [80,90, 100, 200]` also.

Comment: Ok but there will be a one to one correspondence with X1 i mean both X and X1 will have same number of elements right?

Comment: Yes.  X1 can take  value  equal to 0 also making the corresponding area of level1 as 0 %. I mean same number of elements for X and X1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed your dataset into a single JSON.

Just to ensure that mentioned above array x and x1 are related together i made data set like this.

```
data = [{
    major: 100,//this is the X array first element
    minor: 70,//this is the X1 array first element
    grp: 1//here grp is for coloring the segment
}, {
    major: 100,
    minor: 30,
    grp: 2
}, {
    major: 100,
    minor: 50,
    grp: 3
}, {
    major: 140,
    minor: 70,
    grp: 4
}, {
    major: 80,
    minor: 10,
    grp: 5
}];
```

I have made two arc function.

```
var arcMajor = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(function (d) {
    return radius - 10;
})
    .innerRadius(0);

//this for making the minor arc with variable radius as per scale 
var arcMinor = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(function (d) {
    // scale for calculating the radius range([20, radius - 40])
    return scale((d.data.major - d.data.minor));
})
```

This is the code which makes the path.

```
//this makes the major arc
g.append("path")
    .attr("d", function (d) {
    return arcMajor(d);
})
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return d3.rgb(color(d.data.grp));
});

//this makes the minor arcs
g.append("path")
    .attr("d", function (d) {
    return arcMinor(d);
})
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return d3.rgb(color(d.data.grp)).darker(2);//for making the inner path darker
});
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/6e8aue0h/2/) with comments

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent solution Cyril :)

Comment: @Cyril, Thank you very much for your answer but I have tried chnging the data set , pie goes weird. PLease have a look. http://jsfiddle.net/6e8aue0h/3/

Comment: Just a matter of adjusting the scale which returns the inner radius try now http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/6e8aue0h/4/

Comment: @Cyril, Thank you once again. How can we make disappear darker color completely when all the minor values are equal to 0? 

Like in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/6e8aue0h/5/

Comment: @Artiga like i said before its just a matter of how you set teh scale.
as you mentioned above in the comment section the radius is defined by diffrence of major and minor _X2 = X-X1_ in my code fiddle same is done here _return scale((d.data.major - d.data.minor));_ now if major an minor both are same the radius will come 0. as in group 5 check here http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/6e8aue0h/7/
scale is defined as min 0 for making radius 0 
_var scale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, radius - d3.min(data, function (d) {
    return d.major;
})]);_